# How to call a fetch query function in different page(PHP)

Tags: php, function, oop, mysqli

**I have wrote the following code, the data is not fetching .can anyone please help me.** Mostly I do procedural programming so I don't have that much knowledge in oops.

## 1.xyzconfig.php

```
define("HOST", "localhost");            
define("USER", "root");             
define("PASSWORD", "");     
define("DATABASE", "end");
```

## 2.dbconnect.php

```
include_once 'xyzconfig.php';   

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

if($mysqli->connect_error) 

{

header("Location: ../error.php?err=Unable to connect to MySQL");

exit();

}
```

## 3.function.php

```
include_once 'xyzconfig.php';   

 function user_fetch($mysqli)

{

    if($stmt=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username,email,role FROM members"))
    {
        $stmt->execute();   

        $stmt->store_result();

         if($stmt->num_rows == 1)

         {

          while($row=$stmt->fetch_assoc() )
          {

            echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["username"]." ".$row["email"]." ".$row['role']."</td></tr>";

          }

        }    
    }}
```

## 4.test.php

```
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';

include_once 'includes/functions.php';

echo user_fetch($mysqli);
```

Answer (score 0):

functions.php needs to include dbconnect.php not xyzconfig.php

```
include_once 'dbconnect.php';   

 function user_fetch($mysqli)

{

    if($stmt=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username,email,role FROM members"))
    {
        $stmt->execute();   

        $stmt->store_result();

         if($stmt->num_rows >= 1)

         {

          while($row=$stmt->fetch_assoc() )
          {

            echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["username"]." ".$row["email"]." ".$row['role']."</td></tr>";

          }

        }    
    }}
```

test.php needs to be:

```
include_once 'includes/dbconnect.php';

include_once 'includes/functions.php';

echo user_fetch($mysqli);
```

there is absolutely no point in using neither store_result()

Comment: i did that ,but still not fetching

Comment: check your SQL then